# Remove yourself from an account in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

I had one of my clients add me to their Mailchimp account when working on a job in the past, and I'm keep to remove myself from it now that I no longer need to work on it.

If I look under `Account / Settings / Users` I see myself listed, but there doesn't appear to be any option to remove myself from it.

Is this something I can do myself or do I need to get my client to remove me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same issue. Rather than go to `Account`, you need to look under your `Profile`. At the bottom of this section, you will find **Connections and notifications**, where you can then click to **Leave Account**.